# Measure Theory & Functional Analysis for PDE's

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking to take an independent study on Partial Differential Equations. I will hopefully be keeping Walter Strauss' [*Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470054565) and Lawrence Evans' [*Partial Differential Equations*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821849743) as references.

Can someone recommend a textbook that covers the pre-requisite material from measure theory, functional analysis (and maybe even vector calculus) that is used in PDE's. I know a bit of measure theory, and I'll be taking a class on it as well. I haven't studied functional analysis.

It'd be great if someone could recommend a textbook that covers the said pre-requisite material required for PDE's at the level appropriate for the aforementioned books.

Comment: I'm not at the office now but Evans is a huuuuuge book, so it would probably help if you can specify which topics you plan to cover.

Comment: @dbx My intention is to focus on the first part of Evans' textbook, and supplement it by keeping Strauss' textbook on the side. After the first semester, I would also like to study probability theory, so that in the future, I could work my way up towards working in probability theory and PDE's, probably on something like stochastic PDE's. I'm just getting started, but I'd like to start asap.

Comment: @dbx It'd be great if you could recommend a reference, if possible.

Comment: Well, measure theory is covered in most real analysis books. If you search measure theory texts on this site you'll probably find what you want, for instance. My comment was to help you write a question that might get you useful answers.

Comment: @dbx True, but I was specifically looking for a book (on PDE's) that covers the pre-requisite material on measure theory and functional analysis in a self contained manner. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Lang's *Real and Functional Analysis* covers all three topics you mentioned (vector calculus being in the form of differential forms on manifolds). A bonus is that it covers integration of Banach-valued functions.

Brézis's *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations* is tailored to provide the functional analysis background needed for PDEs, but assumes prior knowledge of Lebesgue integration.

Also check the appendices in Evans's book, as he has his own references for the prerequisite material.

Answer (score 0):

> I was specifically looking for a book (on PDE's) that covers the pre-requisite material on measure theory and functional analysis in a self contained manner.

The book Partial Differential Equations by Mikhailov contains all the requisite materials from measure theory and functional analysis in its second and third chapters. However, its quite old.

Instead, if you are willing to learn measure theory elsewhere, the book by [Renardy and Rogers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387004440) is worth considering. The authors develop the required results from functional analysis when required and has a lot of material on PDEs.